# how to make directory by unknown number of variables using python "format"

Tags: python

I am crawling some data with some API(more than 20). Now I want to make dirs whose name is according to the feeded parameters.but the different api will feed different parameters. **So how can I use python "format" to make dir or other things with unknown numbers of variable**

now we have 3 API

> the first one :

```
api_a = {'name': 'test_a',
        'company_status': '01',  # this will be used to dir name
        'code': 'A',   # this will be used to dir name
        'start_page' : 1,
        'per_page' : 100,
        }
```

> the second one :

```
api_b = {'name': 'test_b',
        'business_status': '01', # this will be used to dir nam
        'start_page' : 1,
        'per_page' : 100,
        }
```

> the third one:

```
api_c = {'name': 'test_c',
        'another_para1': 'A', # this will be used to dir nam
        'another_para2': 'B', # this will be used to dir nam
        'another_para3': 'C', # this will be used to dir nam
        'start_page' : 1,
        'per_page' : 100,
        }
```

> here is to read the api and make dirs

```
api_list = [api_a, api_b, api_c]

for api in api_list:

    dir_name = []

    for key, value in api.items():  # is there other more elegant way?
        if key != 'name' and key != 'start_page' and key != 'per_page' :
            dir_name.append(value)

    if not os.path.exists('../crawled_data/{api_name}/{para1}/{para2}/'.format(api_name = api['name'], para1 = dir_name[0], para2=dir_name[1])):

os.makedirs('../crawled_data/{api_name}/{para1}/{para2}'.format(api_name = api['name'], para1 = dir_name[0], para2 = dir_name[1]))

# there will be error here if the number of para not match
```

I have trouble because it will feed 1~3 different parameters in each api and it will be some error when do some stuff in python format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you know which parameters will be used to create the path for each API, if that is the case you can add a format string for each API and loop over them as tuples

```
apis = [
    (api_a, '{company_status}/{code}'),
    (api_b, '{business_status}'),
    (api_c, '{another_para1}/{another_para2}/{another_para3}'),
]

for api, format_string in apis:
    dir_name = format_string.format(api)
```

EDIT:

I don't know if you can guarantee the order of the keys in the response so when we create our key generator we order the keys so that they are always in the same order. Once we have the keys we can just join all the values for those keys with a slash

```
excluded_fields = ('name', 'start_page', 'per_page')
keys = (k for k in sorted(api.keys()) if k not in excluded_fields)
dir_name = '/'.join(api[key] for key in keys):
```

Comment: but actually in my case I have more than 40 APIs to crawl and I should create dirs name according to the value in the para . ex: "status": ['open','close',....]

Comment: Do you know the parameters to be used for creating the path for each API?

Comment: yes. there are 1-3 parameter and in each parameter it will feed more than 10 values

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit but I understand why you would not want to do this

Comment: ya,but sometimes the values in parameter will be tens of thousands ex: business_accounting_no....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using python format, you can achieve this with 'os' library as,

```
api_list = [api_1, api_2, api_3]
const_path = '../crawled_data/' 
for api in api_list:
    path = const_path + os.path.join(api.values())
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)
```

Comment: @ntusteeian Have updated the code to give a clear picture.